# using axios with pug to render

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to display the results of an api call made with axios in my pug template,however this doesnt seem to work

//index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= 'Users List'
  p(id="users") Returned string: #{obj}
```

//allusers_controller

```
var axios = require('axios')

exports.DisplayData = function(req , res){

var obj;
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
axios.get(url).then(response => obj = response.id);
res.render('index.pug',{obj})
}
```

express router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//main controller
var userController = require('../controllers/allusers_controller');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', userController.DisplayData);

module.exports = router;
```

The oBj doesnt is never rendered.What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite understanding how promises work, `.then()` is asynchronous so your code immediately skips to `res.render()` and `obj` is `undefined` --- what you need to do is change it to the following so `res.render` is not called until the response has been received by placing it inside the `.then()`:

```
var axios = require('axios')

exports.DisplayData = function(req , res){    
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  axios.get(url).then(response => {
    let obj = response.id;
    res.render('index.pug',{obj})
  }
}
```

Also, you can alternatively use `async/await` instead of `.then()` like so:

```
exports.DisplayData = async function(req , res){
  try{
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    let obj = response.id;
    res.render('index.pug',{obj});
  }catch(e){
    res.render('error.pug');
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the res.render within the .then callback works.Thanks for that explanation.